# What is the proper way to evaluate ML model when training on time-dependent data?

Tags: model-evaluations

I have a task where I predict a probability of an event happening every month, for which I am using LGBM model and MLflow for model performance tracking. My dataset consists of historical data. In my dataset I have time-dependent features as inflation, interest rate (it’s a task in a banking sphere).

Every month I want to make new predictions and validate model predictions for the previous period, and track how model worsens with time.

When I train model for production I want to record the initial model metrics to be able to track them through time in the future. So far I have been randomly splitting my dataset on train and validation set using sklearn train_test_split and recording model metrics on this validation set. But the problem is that when using this random data split metrics are actually better than in reality, because this random model split allows model to use data “from future” for training and during validation model actually knows about inflation and interest rates from the future.

Example:
In my dataset I have records for 2017-01, 2017-02 and 2017-03. When I randomly split this dataset some records from 2017-03 may end up in validation set as well as in train set and this way improve the prediction results for records from 2017-03.

Alternative option: train model on 2017-01, 2017-02 and validate on 2017-03 in order to simulate the actual life scenario and record more realistic metrics.

The second options sounds more natural to me right now. But my concern is that in this case model is different from the final model that I eventually train on all dataset. In this case I doubt that the metrics that I record on validation set correspond to the actual metrics of my final model.

So, my question is: what is the proper way to evaluate model trained on historical data in order for metrics to be consistent and comparable with real-world scenario? Can I use randomised dataset split, or is it more correct to keep a separate validation data “from the future” that model hasn’t seen and can’t be biased towards it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In prediction topics, you have first to ensure that there is enough data to find patterns and make good predictions.

In your case, I'm not sure if 3 months are enough to detect something. You should at least have 1 or 2 years' records.

If you don't have 1-year records, you can try doing a predictive model with a few months' data, but it might not work very well if there aren't enough detectable patterns.

Regarding train and test data, it's generally good to consider 80% to 90% of training data, and then test it with the last 20% or 10% last ones.

Then, the best way to know if your model works well is to prove its accuracy in the real world: testing its accuracy with test data is good, but it doesn't mean that you'll have a good result with it later.

Therefore, you should validate it by predicting the next day, see if the prediction is correct, record the result, and assign a real score several days later.

About randomness, unless you want to train your model on random periods of time (week or month) and want to find patterns in those periods, you shouldn't apply randomness. In addition to that, the sampling rate is crucial to detect patterns: a too high sampling rate (ex: minutes) wouldn't be effective because most models are not able to have an important memory, whereas a too low sampling rate (ex: month) would only detect some general patterns without any added value.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for response. I actually have 5 years of data, 3 months are just an example to explain my approach. But the basic idea is that I take the validation set not randomly, but rather the latest month (or couple of months) from my dataset? And when the actual result is available I perform the "true" validation of my model.

Comment: Hi Anna, I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.